# fa fa-newspaper-o not showing while all others do

Tags: font-awesome

All my icons are working except for fa-newspaper-o.

I have it set up as:

```
<i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-fw"> &#160;</i>
```

I am using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" >
```

Everything else pulls up just fine.  Please advise.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Did you try viewing the page w other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was addressed already, but I had the exact same problem and resolved it by making sure only one version of FA was being loaded. I've been using the [MediawikiBootstrap skin](https://github.com/nasirkhan/mediawiki-bootstrap) on a site, which loads its own, older version of FA. Disabled that and loaded newer version with CDN. That particular icon ([newspaper](http://fontawesome.io/icon/newspaper-o/)) was then showing up without trouble.